Way to unlink ir_attachment after download it by user
i have code thea create attachment and then allow user to download it, but to keep DB clean is there any way to delete attachment after user download it?
Here my code:
attachment = self.env["ir.attachment"].create({
            'name': file_name,
            'type': 'binary',
            'datas': base64.b64encode(zip_data).decode(),
            'res_model': self._name,
            'store_fname': file_name,
            'mimetype': 'application/zip',
        })
download_url = '/web/content/{attachment_id}?download=true'.format(
            attachment_id=attachment.id
        )
return {
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_url',
            'url': download_url,
            'target': 'self',
        }`

try to find a way to copy file to catch and then attach catch file to url, byt dont find correct way
